VBA Change inside a range
I need the module to Return the address of a modified cell even when pressing Intro without rng.offset(-1,).
When a cell is modified. The module is returning the value of the cell below and not the cell that was modified. Is there a way to return the value of the cell modified before it moves down?
This is what I am doing:
Public xTab As Worksheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set xTab = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")

    Set rng = ActiveCell

    If Not Intersect(Target, xTab.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing And Selection.Count = 1 Then
            Debug.Print rng.Value
    End If

End sub

If I modify cell: A2 and press intro. it will return the value of A3 instead of A2.
Is there a way to avoid this WITHOUT using rng.offset(-1,)?
Thank you!

rng is the ActiveCell and when you press enter first selection move down and later invoke the Change event. Target return the cell address which changed. Set rng = Target

In a worksheet code module you can use Me to refer to the worksheet.

You can simplify to this:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit sub 'only interested in single-cell changes

    If Target.Column = 1 Then Debug.Print Target.Value 'in ColA?
    
End sub

